# Containing 3 divs into 3 columns

Tags: css

So i am trying to set three divs side by side to three columns. Right now the width of each div is overflowing, I'd like to set it so that the contents (text) goes onto a new line when it reaches the length of the div. Here is my code, also here is a link an image for clarification:https://flic.kr/p/22qgZUd

```css
.fd2{
    width: 1212px;
    height: 617px;
    background-color: #bebaba;
    position: absolute;
}
.motherbox div{
    display: flex;
}

#cp{
    font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif;
    font-size: 90px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 7px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
    text-align: right;
}
.one{
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif;
    font-size: 70px;
    color: #EA4335;
    padding: 7px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #9A9A9A;
    width: 30%;
    float: left;

}
.two{
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif;
    font-size: 70px;
    color: #4285F4;
    padding: 7px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #9A9A9A;
    text-align: right;
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
}
.three{
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif;
    font-size: 70px;
    color: #34A853;
    padding: 7px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
    text-align: right;
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
}
div.clear{
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<body>

<!-- particles.js container -->
<div id="particles-js"></div>
<!--<div id="survey"></div>-->

<div class="form-container" id="form" style="display: block;">
    <div class="fd2" style="display: block;">
        <p class="quick" id="surv">
            <h1 id="cp">Quick Survey</h1>
        </p>
        <div class="motherbox">
            <div class="one" id="first">
            <p>1:sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssddddddddddd</p>
            </div>
            <div class="two" id="second">
            <p>2:dddddddddddddddddddddgggggggggggggggggggggg</p>
            </div>
            <div class="three" id="three">
            <p>3:fddggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg</p>
            </div>
            <br style="float: left;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add this css it'll work

```
div p{
   width: 100%;
   overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```css
.fd2{
    width: 1212px;
    height: 617px;
    background-color: #bebaba;
    position: absolute;
}
.motherbox div{
    display: flex;
}

#cp{
    font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif;
    font-size: 90px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 7px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
    text-align: right;
}
.one{
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif;
    font-size: 70px;
    color: #EA4335;
    padding: 7px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #9A9A9A;
    width: 30%;
    float: left;

}
.two{
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif;
    font-size: 70px;
    color: #4285F4;
    padding: 7px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #9A9A9A;
    text-align: right;
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
}
.three{
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif;
    font-size: 70px;
    color: #34A853;
    padding: 7px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
    text-align: right;
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
}
div.clear{
    clear: both;
}
div p{
   width: 100%;
   overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<body>

<!-- particles.js container -->
<div id="particles-js"></div>
<!--<div id="survey"></div>-->

<div class="form-container" id="form" style="display: block;">
    <div class="fd2" style="display: block;">
        <p class="quick" id="surv">
            <h1 id="cp">Quick Survey</h1>
        </p>
        <div class="motherbox">
            <div class="one" id="first">
            <p>1:sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssddddddddddd</p>
            </div>
            <div class="two" id="second">
            <p>2:dddddddddddddddddddddgggggggggggggggggggggg</p>
            </div>
            <div class="three" id="three">
            <p>3:fddggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg</p>
            </div>
            <br style="float: left;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing flexbox's and floating. You can get the desired output with flex alone. You also only need to set the flex css properties on the container not the child divs. A good guide to flexboxes [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

You also need to break your long text in your dummy text example as in Scath's answer (you may not actually want this if you fill the box with normal text as it can be broken on word boundaries by default). Word break options [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp).

To prevent overflow you can use the overflow css properties so that any content in your box is does't jump out of the box (you can either hide it or make is scrollable like in my example below). CSS overflow explanation [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp) .

```css
.fd2 {
  width: 1212px;
  height: 617px;
  background-color: #bebaba;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.motherbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#cp {
  font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif;
  font-size: 90px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 7px;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
  text-align: center;
}

.one,
.two,
.three {
  font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif;
  font-size: 70px;
  color: #EA4335;
  padding: 7px;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #9A9A9A;
  width: 30%;
  word-break: break-all;
}

.two {
  color: #4285F4;
}

.three {
  color: #34A853;
}

div.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!-- particles.js container -->
<div id="particles-js"></div>
<!--<div id="survey"></div>-->

<div class="form-container" id="form">
  <div class="fd2">
    <p class="quick" id="surv">
      <h1 id="cp">Quick Survey</h1>
    </p>
    <div class="motherbox">
      <div class="one" id="first">
        <p>1:sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssddddddddddd</p>
      </div>
      <div class="two" id="second">
        <p>2:dddddddddddddddddddddgggggggggggggggggggggg</p>
      </div>
      <div class="three" id="three">
        <p>3:fddggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif;}
.fd2{
    max-width: 100%;
    background-color: #eee;
}
#cp{
    font-size: 90px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
    text-align: center;
}

.motherbox{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.motherbox > div{
  font-size: 70px;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #9A9A9A;
  line-height: 1.6;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  word-break: break-all;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }
.one{
  color: #EA4335;
}

.two{
  color: #4285F4;
}
.three{
  color: #34A853;
}
```

```html
<body>

<!-- particles.js container -->
<div id="particles-js"></div>
<!--<div id="survey"></div>-->

<div class="form-container" id="form" style="display: block;">
  <div class="fd2" style="display: block;">
    <p class="quick" id="surv"><h1 id="cp">Quick Survey</h1></p>
    <div class="motherbox">
      <div class="one" id="first">
        <p>1:sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssddddddddddd</p>
      </div>
      <div class="two" id="second">
        <p>2:dddddddddddddddddddddgggggggggggggggggggggg</p>
      </div>
      <div class="three" id="three">
        <p>3:fddggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```